# How to dynamically split the column while importing a csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with one column of integer values with a lot of blank rows. These are marks obtained by different students in different subjects, but the thing is not every student has appeared for all the tests, hence, # of rows are different beween each of the blank rows. The data looks like below:

```
63
67
86
90

45
69
90

78
85
40
93
53
55
67

38
92
75
94
73

.
.
.
```

When I try the below script to import this file, it simply ignores the blank rows and the output dataframe looks like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('input_data.txt',header=None)

63
67
86
90
45
69
90
78
85
40
93
53
55
67
.
.
.
```

Comment: What result do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Learn something new every day. Never knew Pandas skipped blank lines by default.

```py
In [4]: pd.read_csv('input_data.txt', header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)
Out[4]:
       0
0   63.0
1   67.0
2   86.0
3   90.0
4    NaN
5   45.0
6   69.0
7   90.0
8    NaN
9   78.0
10  85.0
11  40.0
12  93.0
13  53.0
14  55.0
15  67.0
16   NaN
17  38.0
18  92.0
19  75.0
20  94.0
21  73.0
```

Regarding "split the NaNs to different columns". I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Nonetheless, here are a couple of useful snippets...

```py
# load data
df = pd.read_csv('empty_rows.txt',
                 names=['score'], 
                 skip_blank_lines=False)

# Add an indicator column
df['has_score'] = ~df['score'].isna()

# Split the dataframe into two
gb_isna = df.groupby(~df['score'].isna())
df_has_score = gb_isna.get_group(True)
df_no_score = gb_isna.get_group(False)

# Or use indicator
gb_has_score = df.groupby('has_score')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would also like to split the NaNs to different columns, so that, some manipulations can be done. Any quick way to achieve that? Many thanks

Comment: @pallabbhattacharya, I expanded on the answer a bit.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I think, I might not need to split them into columns, but I need to create a serial number in such a way that for every NaN the serial becomes 0 and it increments by 1 till the next NaN. Can you please help me how to achieve that?

Comment: Try this...

`df['serial_number'] = df['score'].isna().cumsum()`